# Data Annotations for only n character

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

Is there any Data Annotation type for just n character . I do not want to use StringLength, maxlength and minlength. For Example,

```
[DataAnnotationName (ErrorMessage="{0} field must be 10 characters")]
public string SecurtyCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Don't you want to use [RegularExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute?

Comment: why don't you want to use the attributes that are made exactly for this?

Comment: @teovankot how to use it ?

Comment: @Jonesopolis  Because if i use it ,  i have to use to be 2 DataAnnotation. so  
[ maxlength (10), minlength (10) ] . I want to use one DataAnnotation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RegularExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@".{10}", ErrorMessage = "{0} field must be 10 characters")]
public string Bar { get; set; }
```